# Performance issue on ion-slices while using huge amount of items in ionic5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ion-slides(ionic 5) for huge amount items(around 2000 items).
But it causing performance issue.

Can any one suggest any trick to overcome performance issue.

Comment: You can try [Virtual Slides](https://swiperjs.com/api/#virtual)

Comment: One option could be to only have 3 slides and update their content dynamically like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506517/ionic-slides-dynamically-add-slides-before-and-after).